# vir-install virtual machine hang on Probbing EDD

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I'm using vir-stall virtual machine, and my command is

```
 virt-install --name=gust --vcpus=4 --ram=8192 --network bridge:br0 --cdrom=/opt/rhel-server-6.2-x86_64-dvd.iso --disk path=/opt/as1/as1.img,size=50 --accelerate
```

After running the command, it hangs on probing EDD,

```
 -  Press the <ENTER> key to begin the installation process.
      +----------------------------------------------------------+
      |         Welcome to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2!         |
      |----------------------------------------------------------|
      | Install or upgrade an existing system                    |
      | Install system with basic video driver                   |
      | Rescue installed system                                  |
      | Boot from local drive                                    |
      | Memory test                                              |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          |
      +----------------------------------------------------------+

                      Press [Tab] to edit options

                    Automatic boot in 57 seconds...


Loading vmlinuz......
Loading initrd.img...............................ready.
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok




ÿ
```

Previously, I wait a long time, it seems no marching. After I press ctrl + ] and stop it. I find it was running using virsh list, but I cannot console it using virsh concole gust. Any problem and how should I do. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your virt-install

--extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 edd=off"

The edd=off is the critical part for this